# How to add Smarty in wamp php.ini file

Tags: php, smarty, wamp

I need to add libs for smarty in php.ini, but do I find which file I have to add, where can I find the sub directory being included in php directory.....

I have the following error when trying to access the pages on my site in wamp:

```
Warning: require(..../public_html/libs/Smarty.class.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in 

Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required '...../public_html/libs/Smarty.class.php' (include_path='PEAR/') in
```

Apology if the question is too stupid..:)

Comment: `.....` is not exactly a valid path. Perhaps it's just `../public_html` or maybe `../../../public_html`.

Comment: many thanks but I am not sure where I have to find the file in order to see the path

Comment: You were right it is: include_path = "D:/SEAJOBS/source/public_html/libs/Smarty.class.php"... but noting happenning

Comment: Have you installed smarty into that folder?

Comment: Not the greatest documentation but here it is http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/installing.smarty.basic.tpl  You dont need to change anything in the php.ini file.

Comment: on this link you can find the complete procedure http://ubuntu-linux-apache-mysql-php.blogspot.com.br/2009/10/how-to-install-smarty-with-wampserver.html hope it helps.